# What is the meaning of creeds?

Tags: biblical-basis, creeds-and-confessions

What are creeds and how they came about. Is there a Biblical basis for them and how many creeds are there till date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 3 major creeds that every good Catholic knows about are

1. [The Apostles Creed](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01629a.htm)
2. [The Nicene Creed](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11049a.htm) (aka the Nicene-Constantinopolitan Creed)
3. [The Athanasian Creed](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02033b.htm)

There are definitely others, but if you want the 3 most oft repeated ones, you can see the [rest of them here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Christian_creeds) <sub>seems to me that wiki article is lacking a few creeds</sub>.

Now, to find their meaning consider whether the following commandments are in the Bible.

- Did Our Lord want His followers to keep the teaching that He entrusted to them?

> If you love me, you will keep my commandments
>
> [John 14:15 (NABRE)](http://www.usccb.org/bible/john/14:15)

- Did Our Lord want His followers to defend the faith he left with them?

> Always be ready to give an explanation to anyone who asks you for a reason for your hope
>
> [1 Peter 3:15 (NABRE)](http://www.usccb.org/bible/1peter/3:15)

- Were we instructed to hand down the truths that we were given?

> And what you heard from me through many witnesses entrust to faithful people who will have the ability to teach others as well.
>
> [2 Timothy 2:2 (NABRE)](http://www.usccb.org/bible/2timothy2:2)

So, that is why there are creeds.  So that we may keep the faith, so that we can defend the faith and so that we can pass it down.

Comment: So it is a gist of sort of what we believe.

Comment: @jayyeshu-yes, a confession of our beliefs

Comment: Many more creeds are cataloged in Schaff's *Creeds of Christendom* ([vol 1](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds1), [vol 2](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2)) and [*Creeds of the Evangelical Protestant Churches*](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds3), all free online at these links.